# Trouble upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 due to extremely broken system

Tags: upgrade, package-management

I know very little about Ubuntu, but I have a friend who knows even less and still wants to use it. I set out to help this friend upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, as he had some problems ("Could not calculate the upgrade  An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.").

Looking around, I found lots of similar questions here and figured out I had to look in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` to see which packages were broken and then remove them.

This is the result:

```
Broken libglib2.0-0:i386 Breaks on libgnome-desktop-3-2 [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (< 3.4.2-2)
Broken cups-filters:i386 Conflicts on foomatic-filters [ i386 ] < 4.0.16-0ubuntu0.2 -> 4.0.17-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/text )
Broken cups-filters:i386 Conflicts on ghostscript-cups [ i386 ] < 9.05~dfsg-0ubuntu4.2 > ( text )
Broken libunity9:i386 Breaks on unity-common [ i386 ] < 5.20.0-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 7.1.2)
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken xz-utils:i386 Conflicts on xz-lzma [ i386 ] < 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 > ( utils )
Broken tex-common:i386 Breaks on texlive-common [ i386 ] < 2009-15 > ( tex ) (< 2010)
Broken libgoa-1.0-0b:i386 Conflicts on libgoa-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 3.4.0-0ubuntu1.1 > ( libs )
Broken python-ubuntu-sso-client:i386 Breaks on python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 13.05)
Broken indicator-messages:i386 Conflicts on indicator-status-provider-mc5 [ i386 ] < 0.6.0-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome )
Broken indicator-messages:i386 Conflicts on libindicator-messages-status-provider1 [ i386 ] < 0.6.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken evolution-data-server:i386 Breaks on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.2 > ( libs ) (< 3.4)
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:i386 Conflicts on jockey-common [ i386 ] < 0.9.7-0ubuntu7.14 > ( admin )
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:i386 Conflicts on jockey-gtk [ i386 ] < 0.9.7-0ubuntu7.14 > ( admin )
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:i386 Conflicts on jockey-kde [ i386 ] < 0.9.7-0ubuntu7.14 > ( admin )
Broken cups-bsd:i386 Conflicts on lpr [ i386 ] < 1:2008.05.17+nmu1 > ( universe/net )
Broken im-config:i386 Conflicts on im-switch [ i386 ] < 1.20ubuntu5.2 -> 1.23ubuntu1 > ( universe/x11 )
Broken texlive-base:i386 Conflicts on texlive-doc-base [ i386 ] < 2009-2 > ( tex )
Broken python-ubuntuone-client:i386 Depends on python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu1 > ( python ) (>= 3.0.0-0ubuntu1.1)
Broken poppler-data:i386 Breaks on cmap-adobe-japan2 [ i386 ] < 0+20090930-2 > ( fonts ) (<= 0+20090930-2)
Broken poppler-data:i386 Breaks on gs-cjk-resource [ i386 ] < 1.20100103-3 > ( text ) (<= 1.20100103-3)
Broken libgtksourceview-3.0-common:i386 Conflicts on libgtksourceview-3.0-0 [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libmetacity-private0a:i386 Breaks on libmetacity-private0 [ i386 ] < 1:2.34.1-1ubuntu11 > ( libs )
Broken nvidia-331-updates:i386 Conflicts on xorg-driver-binary [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken fonts-droid:i386 Breaks on ttf-droid [ i386 ] < 20101110+git-2 > ( oldlibs ) (< 1:4.2~r1-1~)
Broken wine1.6-i386:i386 Depends on libopencl-1.1-1 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libsnmp30:i386 Breaks on libsnmp15 [ i386 ] < 5.4.3~dfsg-2.4ubuntu1.2 > ( libs )
Broken wine1.6:i386 Depends on wine1.6-i386 [ i386 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs ) (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
Broken nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates:i386 Depends on ocl-icd-libopencl1 [ i386 ] < none -> 2.1.3-4 > ( universe/libs )
Broken nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates:i386 Depends on nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates [ i386 ] < none -> 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4 > ( restricted/misc )
Broken python3-uno:i386 Conflicts on python-uno [ i386 ] < 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu7 > ( python )
Broken libevdocument3-4:i386 Breaks on libevince3-3 [ i386 ] < 3.4.0-0ubuntu1.8 > ( libs )
Broken overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386 Conflicts on liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 [ i386 ] < 0.2.16-0ubuntu1.1 > ( libs ) (< 0.2.16+r348)
Broken overlay-scrollbar-gtk3:i386 Conflicts on liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0 [ i386 ] < 0.2.16-0ubuntu1.1 > ( libs ) (< 0.2.16+r348)
Broken wine1.4-i386:i386 Depends on wine1.6-i386 [ i386 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken language-pack-kde-en:i386 Conflicts on language-pack-kde-en-base [ i386 ] < 1:12.04+20140106 > ( translations )
Broken wine1.4:i386 Depends on wine1.6 [ i386 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken language-pack-kde-zh-hans:i386 Conflicts on language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base [ i386 ] < 1:12.04+20140106 > ( translations )
Broken libmuffin0:i386 Depends on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.6)
Broken libupnp6:i386 Conflicts on libupnp3 [ i386 ] < 1:1.6.6-5.1ubuntu0.12.04.1 > ( libs )
Broken gir1.2-muffin-3.0:i386 Depends on libmuffin0 [ i386 ] < 2.0.5-20131124003821-precise > ( universe/libs )
Broken python-aptdaemon.pkcompat:i386 Depends on python-aptdaemon [ i386 ] < 0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu9 -> 1.1.1-1ubuntu5.1 > ( python ) (= 0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu9)
Broken python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat:i386 Breaks on libpackagekit-glib2-14 [ i386 ] < 0.7.2-4ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken libcuda1-304-updates:i386 Conflicts on libcuda-5.0-1 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken activity-log-manager:i386 Conflicts on activity-log-manager-common [ i386 ] < 0.9.4-0ubuntu3.2 > ( utils )
Broken unity-gtk2-module:i386 Conflicts on appmenu-gtk [ i386 ] < 0.3.92-0ubuntu1.1 > ( libs )
Broken nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates:i386 Conflicts on libopencl1 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libcogl-pango0:i386 Depends on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.6)
Broken ubuntuone-client-data:i386 Breaks on ubuntuone-client [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2 > ( net ) (< 4.1.90-0ubuntu3)
Broken libperl5.14:i386 Depends on perl-base [ i386 ] < 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4 -> 5.18.2-2ubuntu1 > ( perl ) (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4)
Broken unity-gtk3-module:i386 Conflicts on appmenu-gtk3 [ i386 ] < 0.3.92-0ubuntu1.1 > ( libs )
Broken friends-app:i386 Conflicts on gwibber-service [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu2.4 -> 3.7.0bzr13.04.05-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/misc )
Broken gwibber:i386 Depends on friends-app [ i386 ] < none -> 0.92.0+14.04.20140306.1-0ubuntu2 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken python3-speechd:i386 Breaks on python-speechd [ i386 ] < 0.7.1-6ubuntu3 > ( python )
Broken ubuntuone-client-gnome:i386 Depends on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken libedataserverui-3.0-1:i386 Depends on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken idle-python3.2:i386 Depends on python3.2-tk [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libedata-book-1.2-11:i386 Depends on libebook-1.2-12 [ i386 ] < 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.3)
Broken libunity-core-5.0-5:i386 Depends on unity-services [ i386 ] < 5.20.0-0ubuntu3 -> 7.2.4+14.04.20150316-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (= 5.20.0-0ubuntu3)
Broken libexttextcat0:i386 Depends on libexttextcat-data [ i386 ] < 3.2.0-1ubuntu1 -> 3.4.3-1ubuntu1 > ( text ) (= 3.2.0-1ubuntu1)
Broken libvlccore5:i386 Depends on vlc-data [ i386 ] < 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 -> 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 > ( universe/graphics ) (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
Broken libbamf3-0:i386 Depends on bamfdaemon [ i386 ] < 0.2.126-0ubuntu1 -> 0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.2.126-0ubuntu1)
Broken libbamf0:i386 Depends on bamfdaemon [ i386 ] < 0.2.126-0ubuntu1 -> 0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.2.126-0ubuntu1)
Broken ubuntu-sso-client-gtk:i386 Depends on python-ubuntu-sso-client [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 -> 13.10-0ubuntu6 > ( python ) (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu3)
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on gir1.2-muffin-3.0 [ i386 ] < 2.0.5-20131124003821-precise > ( universe/introspection )
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on libcogl-pango0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.7.4)
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.6)
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on libmuffin0 [ i386 ] < 2.0.5-20131124003821-precise > ( universe/libs )
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken python-ubuntu-sso-client:i386 Breaks on python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 13.05)
Broken python-ubuntuone-client:i386 Depends on python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu1 > ( python ) (>= 3.0.0-0ubuntu1.1)
Broken ubuntu-sso-client-qt:i386 Depends on ubuntuone-client-data [ i386 ] < none -> 13.05-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libmuffin0:i386 Depends on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.6)
Broken gir1.2-muffin-3.0:i386 Depends on libmuffin0 [ i386 ] < 2.0.5-20131124003821-precise > ( universe/libs )
Broken libcogl-pango0:i386 Depends on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.6)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:i386 Depends on ubuntu-sso-client-qt [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 -> 13.10-0ubuntu6 > ( python )
Broken ubuntuone-control-panel-qt:i386 Depends on ubuntu-sso-client-qt [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 -> 13.10-0ubuntu6 > ( python ) (>= 2.99.92)
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on gir1.2-muffin-3.0 [ i386 ] < 2.0.5-20131124003821-precise > ( universe/introspection )
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on libcogl-pango0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.7.4)
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.6)
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on libmuffin0 [ i386 ] < 2.0.5-20131124003821-precise > ( universe/libs )
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libcheese-gtk23:i386 Depends on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.13.2)
Broken gnome-control-center:i386 Depends on libcheese-gtk23 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.0)
Broken libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:i386 Depends on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.13.10)
Broken libclutter-gst-2.0-0:i386 Depends on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.13.0)
Broken libtotem0:i386 Depends on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.11.10)
Broken python-ubuntu-sso-client:i386 Breaks on python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 13.05)
Broken empathy:i386 Depends on libcheese-gtk23 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.0)
Broken mcp-account-manager-uoa:i386 Depends on empathy [ i386 ] < 3.4.2.3-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1)
Broken python-ubuntuone-client:i386 Depends on python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu1 > ( python ) (>= 3.0.0-0ubuntu1.1)
Broken ubuntuone-client:i386 Depends on python-ubuntuone-client [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2 > ( python ) (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2)
Broken nautilus-sendto-empathy:i386 Depends on empathy [ i386 ] < 3.4.2.3-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1)
Broken gstreamer1.0-clutter:i386 Depends on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.13.0)
Broken gnome-contacts:i386 Depends on libcheese-gtk23 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.0)
Broken gir1.2-clutter-1.0:i386 Depends on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.16.0)
Broken totem:i386 Depends on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.11.10)
Broken account-plugin-yahoo:i386 Depends on empathy [ i386 ] < 3.4.2.3-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1)
Broken totem-plugins:i386 Depends on libtotem0 [ i386 ] < 3.0.1-0ubuntu21.1 -> 3.10.1-1ubuntu4 > ( video ) (>= 3.10.1-1ubuntu4)
Broken account-plugin-jabber:i386 Depends on empathy [ i386 ] < 3.4.2.3-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1)
Broken account-plugin-salut:i386 Depends on empathy [ i386 ] < 3.4.2.3-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1)
Broken account-plugin-aim:i386 Depends on empathy [ i386 ] < 3.4.2.3-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.1)
Broken python-ubuntuone-control-panel:i386 Depends on python-ubuntuone-client [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2 > ( python ) (>= 2.99.92)
Broken gir1.2-totem-1.0:i386 Depends on libtotem0 [ i386 ] < 3.0.1-0ubuntu21.1 -> 3.10.1-1ubuntu4 > ( video ) (>= 3.10.1-1ubuntu4)
Broken gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0:i386 Depends on libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.2.0-0ubuntu1 -> 1.4.4-3ubuntu2.2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.3.2)
Broken libsyncdaemon-1.0-1:i386 Depends on ubuntuone-client [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2 > ( net ) (>= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2)
Broken ubuntuone-control-panel:i386 Depends on python-ubuntuone-control-panel [ i386 ] < 3.0.1-0ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.0.1-0ubuntu1)
Broken libubuntuoneui-3.0-1:i386 Depends on libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2 > ( libs )
Broken totem-mozilla:i386 Depends on totem [ i386 ] < 3.0.1-0ubuntu21.1 -> 3.10.1-1ubuntu4 > ( gnome ) (= 3.10.1-1ubuntu4)
Broken cheese:i386 Depends on libcheese-gtk23 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.0)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:i386 Depends on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.3 -> 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome )
Broken gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0:i386 Depends on libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 [ i386 ] < 3.0.1-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.99.3)
Broken ubuntuone-couch:i386 Depends on python-ubuntuone-client [ i386 ] < 3.0.2-0ubuntu2.2 > ( python )
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on cinnamon-control-center [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.3 -> 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome )
Broken libcogl15:i386 Breaks on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 1.15)
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken unity-control-center:i386 Depends on libcheese-gtk23 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.0)
Broken gnome-control-center:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-2 [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken gnome-control-center:i386 Depends on libgoa-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 3.4.0-0ubuntu1.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.1.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:i386 Depends on gnome-control-center-data [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.3 -> 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome ) (< 1:3.5)
Broken libcheese7:i386 Depends on libclutter-gst-2.0-0 [ i386 ] < none -> 2.0.8-1build1 > ( libs ) (>= 0.10.0)
Broken libgoa-1.0-0b:i386 Conflicts on libgoa-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 3.4.0-0ubuntu1.1 > ( libs )
Broken unity-settings-daemon:i386 Breaks on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.3 -> 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome ) (< 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu35)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:i386 Breaks on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.3 -> 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome ) (< 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu35)
Broken libgoa-1.0-common:i386 Breaks on libgoa-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 3.4.0-0ubuntu1.1 > ( libs ) (< 3.8.2)
Broken libgoa-backend-1.0-1:i386 Depends on libgoa-1.0-0b [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.3-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.7.90)
Broken unity-control-center-signon:i386 Depends on unity-control-center [ i386 ] < none -> 14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken libgdata13:i386 Depends on libgoa-1.0-0b [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.3-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.1.90)
Broken gnome-session-flashback:i386 Depends on unity-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < none -> 14.04.0+14.04.20140606-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome )
Broken evolution-data-server-online-accounts:i386 Depends on libgoa-1.0-0b [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.3-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.7.91)
Broken gir1.2-gdata-0.0:i386 Depends on libgdata13 [ i386 ] < 0.12.0-1 -> 0.14.1-1 > ( libs ) (>= 0.13.3)
Broken gir1.2-goa-1.0:i386 Depends on libgoa-1.0-0b [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.3-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.7.91)
Broken policykit-desktop-privileges:i386 Breaks on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6.6 -> 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 > ( gnome ) (< 3.6.4-0ubuntu8)
Broken webaccounts-extension-common:i386 Depends on unity-control-center-signon [ i386 ] < none -> 0.1.7~+14.04.20140211.2-0ubuntu4 > ( gnome )
Broken webaccounts-extension-common:i386 Depends on gnome-control-center-signon [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xul-ext-webaccounts:i386 Depends on webaccounts-extension-common [ i386 ] < none -> 0.5-0ubuntu2 > ( web ) (= 0.5-0ubuntu2)
Broken ubuntu-session:i386 Depends on unity-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < none -> 14.04.0+14.04.20140606-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome )
Broken gnome-session-fallback:i386 Depends on gnome-session-flashback [ i386 ] < none -> 1:3.8.0-1ubuntu12.2 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken gnome-online-accounts:i386 Depends on libgoa-1.0-0b [ i386 ] < none -> 3.10.3-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 3.10.3-0ubuntu1)
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-2:i386 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2)
Broken libglib2.0-0:i386 Breaks on libgnome-desktop-3-2 [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (< 3.4.2-2)
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-7:i386 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libcogl15:i386 Breaks on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 1.15)
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken gnome-session-bin:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.7.90)
Broken gnome-control-center:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-2 [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:i386 Breaks on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6.6 -> 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 > ( gnome ) (< 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu8)
Broken indicator-keyboard:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.5.2)
Broken indicator-bluetooth:i386 Depends on unity-control-center [ i386 ] < none -> 14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken indicator-bluetooth:i386 Depends on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.3 -> 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome )
Broken indicator-bluetooth:i386 Depends on ubuntu-system-settings [ i386 ] < none -> 0.1+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu2 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.7.90)
Broken unity-greeter:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.7.90)
Broken nautilus:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken unity-scope-gdrive:i386 Depends on gir1.2-gdata-0.0 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.14.1-1 > ( libs )
Broken gnome-panel:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken unity:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken unity-lens-photos:i386 Depends on gir1.2-gdata-0.0 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.14.1-1 > ( libs )
Broken gnome-screensaver:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.7.3)
Broken gnome-applets:i386 Depends on gnome-panel [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1.2 -> 1:3.8.0-1ubuntu12.2 > ( universe/gnome ) (>= 2.91.91)
Broken nautilus-sendto:i386 Depends on nautilus [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu9 -> 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7 > ( gnome ) (>= 1:2.91)
Broken gnome-session:i386 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon [ i386 ] < 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6.6 -> 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.0)
Broken gnome-font-viewer:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken eog:i386 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 [ i386 ] < none -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken nautilus-share:i386 Depends on nautilus [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu9 -> 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7 > ( gnome ) (>= 2.10)
Broken unity-2d:i386 Depends on unity [ i386 ] < 5.20.0-0ubuntu3 -> 7.2.4+14.04.20150316-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken unity-2d-panel:i386 Depends on unity [ i386 ] < 5.20.0-0ubuntu3 -> 7.2.4+14.04.20150316-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken libunity-2d-private0:i386 Depends on unity [ i386 ] < 5.20.0-0ubuntu3 -> 7.2.4+14.04.20150316-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken unity-2d-shell:i386 Depends on unity [ i386 ] < 5.20.0-0ubuntu3 -> 7.2.4+14.04.20150316-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken unity-2d-common:i386 Depends on unity [ i386 ] < 5.20.0-0ubuntu3 -> 7.2.4+14.04.20150316-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken unity-2d-spread:i386 Depends on unity [ i386 ] < 5.20.0-0ubuntu3 -> 7.2.4+14.04.20150316-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on cinnamon-control-center [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on gnome-control-center [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13.3 -> 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome )
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on gnome-panel [ i386 ] < 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1.2 -> 1:3.8.0-1ubuntu12.2 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken cinnamon:i386 Depends on tint2 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.11+svn20121014-1 > ( universe/x11 )
Broken libcogl15:i386 Breaks on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 1.15)
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken nemo:i386 Depends on cinnamon [ i386 ] < 2.0.14-20131203040103-precise > ( gnome )
Broken cinnamon-screensaver:i386 Depends on cinnamon [ i386 ] < 2.0.14-20131203040103-precise > ( gnome )
Broken nemo-fileroller:i386 Depends on nemo [ i386 ] < 2.0.8-20131203010008-precise > ( universe/misc )
Broken unity-2d:i386 Depends on unity-2d-panel [ i386 ] < 5.14.0-0ubuntu2 -> 7.2.4+14.04.20150316-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/x11 )
Broken libcogl15:i386 Breaks on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 1.15)
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl15:i386 Breaks on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 1.15)
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl15:i386 Breaks on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 1.15)
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl15:i386 Breaks on libclutter-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < 1.10.6-1~precise1 -> 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (< 1.15)
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:i386 Breaks on libcogl9 [ i386 ] < 1.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
```

It's a real mess, half the system is broken! Is there anyway to fix this? It seems both extremely time consuming and potentially dangerous to manually remove each broken package. What to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which command do you use to update?

Comment: My advice would be to back up any personal data that you want to keep, and then do a fresh install of 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure whether to post this as an answer or edit to my original post, but here goes: I had reason to believe Cinnamon was, at least partially, causing all the conflicts and whatnot (things in general weren't looking/working like they're supposed to) so I removed all associated packages with Synaptic, plus all other 3d party packages and then tried upgrading through the Update Manager and it actually worked! Problem solved, but thanks for the tips guys!

Comment: Come back at least 48 hours after you posted the question and you can mark your own answer as accepted by clicking the check mark beside it, which changes its color to green.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all make a copy of every important files you have on the system!**

After that you can try the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that doesn't help, you should reinstall the system.